# How to consume events from and affect changes to Firestore v2 via Cloud Functions for Firebase Gen 2?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to use `Cloud Functions for Firebase Gen 2` to process events from and then do operations on other documents in `Firestore v2`.

Consuming events is working fine, but I cannot figure out how to use `Firestore v2` to query and change other documents. The examples provided by GCP are terrible and they conflate and cross-link between `v1` and `v2`. Perhaps there's no way to write via `v2`, but that seems unlikely.

I would ideally like to be streaming query results rather than getting them up front in bulk (so as to manage the memory footprint of the running Cloud Function).

Does anyone have experience using `v2` to do Firestore operations? Or even if you could point me to reliable and recent examples? Thanks!

```
const {logger, firestore} = require("firebase-functions");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const {onDocumentUpdated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

exports.update = 
    onDocumentUpdated('/rep/{docId}', (event) => {
        const old_doc = event.data.before.data();
        const new_doc = event.data.after.data();
        const rep_id =  event.params.docId;

        const doc_deleted = !event.data.after.exists;

        const changed_name = old_doc.name == new_doc.name;
        console.log('changed_name', changed_name);

        const query = db.doc('help_user_reps/{userRepId}').where('ref_rep', '==', rep_id).get();
        if (changed_name || doc_deleted) {
            query.stream().on('data', (doc) => {
                if (doc_deleted) {
                    // document was deleted
                    console.log('doc to delete:', doc.id);
                    doc.delete();
                }
                else {
                        console.log('doc to update name:', doc.name);
                        doc.update({ 'rep_name': new_doc.rep_name });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the Admin SDK [`stream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#stream) method in a Cloud Function.I would recommend using a standard query and a batched write.

However there is an error in your query definition:

```js
const query = db
          .doc("help_user_reps/{userRepId}")
          .where("ref_rep", "==", rep_id)
          .get();
```

is not correct.

It should probably be

```js
const query = db
          .collection("help_user_reps")
          .where("ref_rep", "==", rep_id)
          .get();
```

Therefore the CF code should be as follows (untested):

```js
    const {log} = require("firebase-functions/logger");
    const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
    const {getFirestore} = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
    const {onDocumentUpdated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

    initializeApp();
    const db = getFirestore();
    
    exports.update = onDocumentUpdated("/rep/{docId}", async (event) => {
      try {
        const old_doc = event.data.before.data();
        const new_doc = event.data.after.data();
        const rep_id = event.params.docId;
    
        const doc_deleted = !event.data.after.exists;
    
        const changed_name = old_doc.name == new_doc.name;
        log("changed_name", changed_name);
    
        const query = db
          .collection("help_user_reps")
          .where("ref_rep", "==", rep_id)
          .get();
    
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
    
        if (querySnapshot.size > 0 && (changed_name || doc_deleted)) {
          const batch = db.batch();
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
            if (doc_deleted) {
              // document was deleted
              log("doc to delete:", doc.id);
              batch.delete(docSnapshot.ref);
            } else {
              log("doc to update name:", doc.name);
              batch.update(docSnapshot.ref, { rep_name: new_doc.rep_name });
            }
          });
          // Commit the batch
          await batch.commit();
        }
    
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        log(error);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Ahh I do indeed see how that would be wrong. Thanks! Re: not using streams... is this a preference thing, or is there a reason that you would not use streams in CF? I went with streams to ensure that I wasn't getting a giant batch of data at once and blowing the CF memory out.

Comment: For added context, I now have it running seemingly-ok with a Stream version, but curious if there are gotchas about using Streams in GCF!